# Python - import in if

Tags: python, if-statement, python-import

I wrote little wrapper for urllib (python3). Is it **proper** and **safe** to import module *in if*?

```
if self.response_encoding == 'gzip':
    import gzip
```

I didn't find any PEP about this code. However, it bothers me.

Comment: just be sure not to call any function coming from this package if it is not imported

Comment: Yes it is. Why does it bother you?

Comment: I wanted to ask and be sure. Maybe I should use 'worried' word. English isn't my native language.

Comment: It bothers people, I think, because in other languages, constructs similar to 'import' are static declarations,  whereas in python they are executable.  One tip: You can do 'from x import *' inside a function. But don't. Because it means that function now has a local variable set which can't be determined when the function is compiled, so the func has different internals which are messier and slower, and local vars can be clobbered. (same if you do an 'exec' in a func without using 'in'). These usages are deprecated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Python standard library uses it, so it is most definitely proper and safe. See the [`os` module source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/os.py) for an excellent example:

> ```
> if 'posix' in _names:
>     name = 'posix'
>     linesep = '\n'
>     from posix import *
>     try:
>         from posix import _exit
>     except ImportError:
>       pass
>     import posixpath as path
>     import posix
>     __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(posix))
>     del posix
> ```

It's quite common to conditionally import modules in python. Instead of `if`, you'll often see a `try:`/`except ImportError:` combination too:

```
try:
    from subprocess import check_output
except ImportError:
    # Python 2.6 and before
    def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
        from subprocess import Popen
        if 'stdout' in kwargs:
            raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be '
                             'overridden.')
        process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
        output, unused_err = process.communicate()
        retcode = process.poll()
        if retcode:
            cmd = kwargs.get("args")
            if cmd is None:
                cmd = popenargs[0]
            raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
        return output
```

Here, we basically use the moral equivalent of an `if` test: If you can import `check_output`, do so, otherwise define the full function here.

An import statement is just a re-binding of an external piece of code to a local name. Using an `if` control flow to control the import is no different from assigning a variable in an `if` statement in that regard. You need to make sure you don't end up using the name without it being defined either way.

Comment: +1 -- `try/except ImportError` was my first instinct to answer this question as well.

Answer (score 19):

This is a reasonably common idiom actually.  You'll sometimes see it to pick between different modules:

```
if system == 'linux':
   import linuxdeps as deps
elif system == 'win32':
   import win32deps as deps
```

Then, assuming both `linuxdeps` and `win32deps` have the same functions, you can just use it:

```
deps.func()
```

This is even used to get `os.path` in the standard library (some of the source code for `os` follows):

```
if 'posix' in _names:
    name = 'posix'
    linesep = '\n'
    from posix import *
    try:
        from posix import _exit
    except ImportError:
        pass
    import posixpath as path

    import posix
    __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(posix))
    del posix

elif 'nt' in _names:
    name = 'nt'
    linesep = '\r\n'
    from nt import *
    try:
        from nt import _exit
    except ImportError:
        pass
    import ntpath as path

    import nt
    __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(nt))
    del nt
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, that's fine. It can even be necessary in cases where the module has initialization code that you don't always want to run.

Answer (score 3):

Is it safe? Yes. As [Martijin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860841/python-import-in-if#answer-12861052) pointed out that Official Python use this.

Is it proper? Depends. [Python performance docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead) points out that even though python can avoid import the same module, there is still overhead.

So i believe you should ask yourself, how often the if statement is true. If very often, then there will be large overhead, and you should import it at the beginning of the file. If not often, then import in if statement is a wise choice.